# What is the correct folder permission to allow users to upload a file

Tags: security, file-permissions

What is the correct folder permission to allow users to upload a file in it ?
As the example, it a normal user, press upload button on a website and i upload it on backend through a normal php-script.
I know its dangerous to let the folder on 777, but that is the only way  I know right now to let the user upload a file.
The webserver i'm using is laravel on Apache, i have a vps, how can i let my users (user of the website) not people who can run any script, as the 'webuser'. who has the write permissions?, maybe that's the answer i'm looking for. Just information, i'm not experienced in server things,

Say we have site like Facebook where each user can upload own picture.

Comment: When you say file permission, are you talking about the file you are going to upload or are you talking about the folder permission where you are going to upload ? Upload how ? FTP, rsync, webDAV ?

Comment: By `like Facebook` if you mean that you have a web server, all you need is to run the server with a user, say `webuser`, and then  save the file to a directory where `webuser` has write permissions. You should still be restrictive on others...

Comment: hi @pun i mean folder permission where i upload. As the example, it a normal user, press upload button on a website. and i upload it on backend through a normal php-script

Comment: @Jedi yes, i have a vps, how can i let my users(user of the website) not people who can run any script, as the 'webuser' who has the write permissions, maybe that's the answer i'm looking for. Just information, i'm not experienced in server things,

Comment: @Hilmanrdn what web server and framework are you using for the website? Did you read the docs?

Comment: @jedi i'm using laravel on Apache and yes i read the docs, also googled already, not find any answer, for this question .. thanks

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache

Answer (score 0):

To implement such functionality you can use 777 folder and a script that will copy all new files to private folder.

Comment: I don't thing OP wants arbitrary copying in of files. `777` also allows the uploader to access others' files and delete them...

Comment: You are right about delete permissions, that why I suggested to copy all files to private folder. Kind of one way uploading.

Comment: Yeah, but this isn't foolproof.  Nothing prevents the "uploader" from monitoring and duplicating files, or corrupting file writes....